# Change code while debugging python program in Visual Studio Code

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger

Is it possible to change the code while debugging in VSCode and that the change will take effect immediately without rerun the code?
I'm using Microsoft Python extension.

Comment: I don't think that's possible in any language.  You can change code while a program is running, but you still have to re-run the code to see the change.

Comment: In vba it's possible.

Comment: @Adirmola But generally not in other languages.

Comment: Too bad. I really don't understand why not, it's a big advantage in debugging.

Comment: Yeah, that would be a nice feature. Seems like Eclipse IDE can do it with [Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12661114/how-to-modify-java-code-while-running-in-debug-mode/12661165#12661165) and [Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23333815/is-there-edit-and-continue-in-pycharm-reload-code-into-running-program-like-i).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [There is a way to change the code while debugging in python using vscode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68276083/there-is-a-way-to-change-the-code-while-debugging-in-python-using-vscode)

Answer (score 2):

So, apparently that the closest way of doing it is to use Jupyter capabilities (that can be use via VSCode).

With Jupyter you can split your code to multiple cells and run every each one of them separately without run all from beginning.

Answer (score 1):

It depends. There's no such thing as a hot reload in Python. The closest you can come is `importlib.reload()`, but realize that only reloads the module and not the objects which already exist in memory. IOW it typically doesn't do what you want in code (it's usually used in the REPL).